# Link to view PDF version of a Google Docs

Tags: google-docs, pdf

I think there used to be a way to link to the PDF version of a Google Docs, but now I can only make a link that *downloads* the PDF instead of viewing it in the browser. Does anybody know if the old technique is still supported? I found several discussions in the Google support forum, but nothing definitive. The [Google Docs API](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#DownloadingDocsAndPresentations) only lists the download method, so I suspect I'm out of luck.

Just to be clear, I want to link to a PDF file that gets automatically updated whenever the Google Docs changes.

Comment: Hook https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/90158/10579

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Replace the beginning of the url with the Google Docs viewer.

This is what you need:

**https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=**`https://docs.google.com/x/yyyy/document/z/nvjsinmsdfjnlsnlkkn-hslknl1_V7sc`**/export?format=pdf**

Comment: worked like magic, thanks!

Answer (score 20):

You can do it by using the *Export as PDF* tool like this:

Your document link (example):

`https://docs.google.com/x/yyyy/document/z/nvjsinmsdfjnlsnlkkn-hslknl1_V7sc`**/edit**

Change the end of link from `/edit` to `/export?format=pdf`

`https://docs.google.com/x/yyyy/document/z/nvjsinmsdfjnlsnlkkn-hslknl1_V7sc`**/export?format=pdf**

However this needs **Sharing setting** to be modified **Anyone who has the link can view**

It works with:

```
/export?format=docx
/export?format=odt
/export?format=rtf
/export?format=pdf
/export?format=txt
/export?format=html
```

Comment: There are several options for exporting a PDF. Here are arguments that download a letter-size PDF fit-to-page, landscape orientation, with title, row headers on each page, no gridlines, no sheet name, no page numbers: `export?format=pdf&size=0&fzr=true&portrait=false&fitw=true&gid=0&gridlines=true&printtitle=true&sheetnames=false&pagenum=UNDEFINED&attachment=true`

Comment: This will download the PDF... Will not open a view in the browser

Comment: @QuinnComendant Great comment! Is there any parameters to set margin at each side?

Answer (score 4):

To preview in PDF-like format, add `/preview` at the end, e.g.

```
https://docs.google.com/document/d/DOCS_ID/preview
```

To export as PDF, use the following URL structure:

```
https://docs.google.com/document/export?format=pdf&id=DOCS_ID
```

Example `wget` command:

```
wget --content-disposition "https://docs.google.com/document/export?format=pdf&id=1QtgW1rdyqaGVP3cqDSagTacewsND41t22hD3hdS7b-w"
```

Comment: this is almost perfect for me, but printing from the link is awkward

Answer (score 3):

It took me a lot of struggle and the very helpful comment by @Quinn Comendant to figure this one out.

The url needs to end with: 
`/export?format=pdf&attachment=false`

example: 
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1PjO5dM4KQLWBFU2IzBE5gINwFU13ub9uvVRywk2Hx_s/export?format=pdf&attachment=false

Comment: Your link doesn't work. It's just a blank page with no content. Same for my link when I set `attachment=false`

Comment: This is the perfect answer. Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

**Publishing a Google Document as a PDF is not supported yet :(**

(Though it **IS** supported for Spreadsheets...)

Comment: When wil it be supported? It's like 5 years...

Answer (score 1):

After you click on the PDF, you will notice a Share link on the top-left corner. Select Sharing Settings option from the menu & change the settings to "Public on the web" or "Anyone with the link" instead of the default which is Private.

When you share that link, others can view it within the browser without having to download the PDF

Comment: That lets me link to the HTML version of the doc, but the PDF version still requires a sign in and then just downloads instead of displaying in the browser. Did I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 0):

1. Click 'Print' or the icon for the printer in the Google Drive.
2. At the 'Destination' field, click the 'Change' button and choose "Save to Google Drive" as your destination. 
   If "Save to Google Drive" does not display as an option among your printers,

   2a. Select 'Show All' at the bottom of your list and it should display. 
   Or, type 'google drive' in the 'Search Destinations' field.
3. Click 'Save'
4. Go to your Google Drive homepage and select 'Recent' to display your new .pdf file
5. Rename or organize at will.