# Is it possible to download a published Google Docs as PDF?

Tags: google-docs, download, pdf

I have a published Google Docs on my site and I want users to have the option to download the file as a PDF. It's not important if the link will be within the HTML page or on my site.

[Link to view PDF version of a Google Doc](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8106/link-to-view-pdf-version-of-a-google-docquestion) is old, and not answering my question.

I’m not sure how I can use [Making download link to DOMPDF generated pdf on same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987968/making-download-link-to-dompdf-generated-pdf-on-same-page), since I need to have that on the HTML/within the Google Docs page, and I can't edit the server pages there.

Comment: The user's system/preferences decide how to handle a PDF file. Short of providing a file type that a browser cannot open (like a zip), there is no way to force a link to a PDF to download versus opening in the browser.

Comment: @phantom42 I know. I need a link to the PDF. Using instructions, the user will either have to 'right click' save, or view/print from the browser. currently, I only able to get html format - not good for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

This question was almost already answered [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/30654/in-google-drive-how-can-you-link-directly-to-download-a-zip-file-and-not-view).

To export the document as a PDF, the correct URL is `https://docs.google.com/uc?export=pdf&id=YourIndividualID`

Comment: This worked for a ZIP, JPG file - and others that are stroed as files. I need it to work for a google doc. and export as PDF

Answer (score 1):

For example:
docs.google.com/document/d/[FILE_ID]/export?format=pdf

e.g.: docs.google.com/document/d/1-KPW5iiNsmRiloTPMJ6DgQ2tJ4s8UvFXnA_fN1j9Jvk/export?format=pdf

[Source](http://techathlon.com/download-shared-files-google-drive/)

Answer (score -2):

File > Download As > PDF Document (.pdf)