# Link to view PDF version of a Word Online doc

Tags: office-365, pdf, word-online

I create documents which I update frequently, I share these with a link which turns the document into a pdf when clicked ensuring whoever clicks the link always gets the most up to date, pdf version.

I am moving from Google Docs to Office 365.

I found this question on this website a while ago now and the solution works perfectly for Google Docs: [Link to view PDF version of a Google Docs](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8106/link-to-view-pdf-version-of-a-google-docs)

As I am moving to Office 365 my question is can I do the same with a document created with the online version of Word?

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.